# What is the meaning of transfer logs originating from the address "0x00...00"?

Tags: tokens, logs

Some Ethereum transfer event logs have the address `0x000..00` in their from field. such as the log in the image, from tx with hash `0x60085d9f157a8426b3d2795de6cebbd4b50d541445be08e23f2b458d4bd0e60e`

[image: log image]

What is the significance of this? What does this mean? I am guessing that it means new tokens are being minted but I do not want to assume anything.

If it is minting new tokens, where do the tokens go in the log when the tokens are being burned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the deposit of Dai token in some service, let's say staking. In regard the staking the `tDai` is being minted to the Depositor's address and obviously that is from `0x0` address (`Transfer` event from `0x0` address to the Depositor).

In this the Depositor posses `tDai` which is the reference value of amount of `Dai` the Depositor has Deposited in the contract so that when the Depositor wants to withdraw the `Dai` his tDai will be burnt and equal amount of `Dai` will be sent back to the Depositor's address. During withdraw process it will again emit the `Transfer` event that will be from Depositor address to `0x0` address.

The burnt tokens are just subtracted from Depositor address and also from total supply.

eg.

```
balances[Depositor] -= amount;
totalSupply -= amount;
emit Transfer(Depositor, address(0), amount)
```

Comment: The code example is for burning tokens, right? What would be the equivalent code for the log, in the question? Also, is address(0) the same as "0x00...00"?

Comment: yes address(0) is same as the zero address in solidity. For log it is `emit Transfer(Depositor, address(0), amount)` for burning but for new minting it is `emit Transfer(address(0), Depositor, tDaiAmount)`

Comment: Why doesn't tDai use `Deposit` and `Withdraw` events instead of the `Transfer` event with null sender or receiver?